# WebView does not load html files after displaying about:blank

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am trying to load local html files in webview, but I want it to display a blank screen if the file is not found

The code to display a blank page is as shown below, inside my class which extends WebViewClient

```
@Override  

public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String dewscription, String failingUrl) {  
  //Error happened during webpage loading  
  if(description.equals("net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND") ){  
     view.loadUrl("about:blank");
     view.invalidate();  
  }
```

This gets called in the beginning when the file to be displayed does not exist, and it shows a blank screen as needed

After some time has passed the program creates an html file in the internal memory, and I have another loadUrl() function that should load this created html file

However, the webView continues to stay blank. If I don't call the `view.loadUrl("about:blank");` function, the created html files get loaded as expected, but the standard error page is displayed when the html file is not found

How can I force the webview to display a blank page, only when html file is not present? Note: `webview.clearView()` doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Have u tried this **`view.loadData("about:blank", "text/html", "UTF-8");`**

Comment: @Nilesh I  just tried it it just displays the text about:blank instead, but otherwise has the same problem